# How to display Metafield in Shopify Cart Items

Tags: javascript, shopify, alpine.js, shopify-template

I want to display metafield in Shopify Cart Items. I did that on this way:
{{ product.metafields.custom.reviews }}

In one product on this metafield I insert "ssssss", on second product I insert "ddddddd". Now when I looked into my Cart I can see this:
[Metafield in Cart Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPmBn.png)

On both products I can see "ddddddd" only If I am on product page with metafield "ddddddd". If I am on collection page or Home page and I opened the Cart I can't see that metafield in Cart Items.

How can I display metafield for each product separately ?

My code looks like this:

[Check the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYWIA.png)

I need help to fix this.

Comment: Your loop variable is `cartItem`, but you use `product` inside the loop. What is `product`? Where do you define it? Why don't you use the `cartItem` loop everywhere in the loop?

Comment: I tried to use cartItem.metafield.custom.reviews but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% if item.product.metafields.custom.reviews %}
   {{ item.product.metafields.custom.reviews }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can use Metafields on cart page like the above code.
Using this code you will the product Metafields value in cart page.

Comment: This code works, but it has one problem. The metafield is showing in the cart page but not immediately. Metafield is showing only if we refresh the cart page. How can we fix this?

Comment: Which Shopify theme are you using? and Did you update the cart page code and JavaScript?

Comment: I update the cart with this code: {% for item in cart.items %}
  {% if item.product.metafields.custom.reviews %}
   {{ item.product.metafields.custom.reviews }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: but it is showing only when we refresh the page, not immediately